# How to get graph API Access token using custom Proxy

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get graph API Access token using custom proxy using below Code and Getting error:

> Executed 'xxxx' (Failed, Id=52032de5-a5da-43bb-b5aa-9ca16a2b99c0, Duration=43385ms)
> [2024-02-16T12:26:05.484Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: xxxx. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (No such host is known. (http:80)). System.Net.Http: No such host is known. (http:80). System.Net.Sockets: No such host is known.

Code Snippet

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_options.O365ClientId)
    .WithClientSecret(_options.O365ClientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri($"{Constants.GraphAPILogInUri}{_options.O365TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token"))                    
   ** .WithHttpClientFactory(new HttpClientFactoryWithProxy(
        _options.HttpProxyHost,
        Convert.ToInt32(_options.HttpProxyPort), logger))**
    .Build();
var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
accessToken = result.AccessToken;
```

HttpClientFactoryWithProxy class is below

```
internal class HttpClientFactoryWithProxy : IMsalHttpClientFactory, IDisposable
{

    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    ILogger _logger;

    public HttpClientFactoryWithProxy(string proxyHost, int proxyPort, ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(CreateHttpClientHandler(proxyHost, proxyPort), true);
       
    }

    ~HttpClientFactoryWithProxy()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Http Client Factory WithProxy Dispose called");
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _httpClient?.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(true);
    }

    public HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Http Client Factory WithProxy HttpClient called");
        return _httpClient;
    }

    public static HttpClientHandler CreateHttpClientHandler(string proxyHost, int proxyPort)
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.None,
            UseProxy = true,
            Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort)
        };
    }
}
```

How to get access token using custom Proxy.

Comment: Try with HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: Tried with https but getting same error as in question

Comment: From cmd.exe, can you ping the host?